# Bluetooth RFComm Read crashing app

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm running a Bluetooth server on my laptop and a Bluetooth client in my app. The app happily connects to the server and can write data perfectly fine. However, when I add the read() capability the app crashes. It looks like the UI thread is being held up by this command but I can't figure out why because I thought I was running it in a separate thread. I don't have a great deal of experience with threading so I'm assuming I've missed something important. Does anyone have any clues?

Main Activity:

```
public void startBluetoothConnection(BluetoothDevice device){
    alreadyConnecting = true;
    btConnection = new ConnectionService(this, device);
    manageConnectionService = btConnection.startConnection();
    //This line causes the problem...
    manageConnectionService.read();
}
```

ManageConnectionService:

```
public class ManageConnectionService extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
private final InputStream mInStream;
private final OutputStream mOutStream;
private Context mContext;

public static final String tag = "MANAGECONNECTIONSERVICE";

public ManageConnectionService(Context context, BluetoothSocket socket){
    mContext = context;
    mSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    try{
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(tag, e.toString());
    }

    mInStream = tmpIn;
    mOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void read() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    int m;
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(100);

    while (true) {
        try {
                    m = mInStream.read();
                    Log.i("MESSAGE RECEIVED", buffer.toString() + " length = " + m);

                    // if it's the end of the message...
                    if (m == 37) {
                        Log.i(tag, "End of message " + message.toString());
                        //Do stuff here

                        message = new StringBuilder(100);
                    } else {
                        message.append(Character.toString((char) m));
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(tag, e.toString());
                    break;
                }
    }
}

public void write(byte[] bytes){
    try{
        mOutStream.write(bytes);
        Log.i(tag, "Sent message!");
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(tag, e.toString());
    }
}

public void cancel(){
    try{
        mSocket.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(tag, e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think that m == 37 is the end of the message? m contains the number of bytes read from your InputStream. If you know the length of your message, you might want to use DataInputStream and readFully(). You need to be a litte more precise on your actual scenario, assumptions and goals here.

Comment: 37 is the integer for '%' which I'm appending to my messages on the sending side. It's just a special character to indicate the end of the message because the message could be a different length each time at the moment.  I think the problem is to do with my implementation of the while loop, it never seems to pause to let anything else happen.